# Is it possible to format data in CDATA section in xml file to display information into 2 sections using style = float: left setting?

Tags: xml, cdata

I am trying to split the page into 2 frames to display sets of information. But struggling to set the style options. Can someone please suggest me a way around this please?

Thanks in advance.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <system>
    <parameter name="Text">

    <![CDATA[  <b>Summary:</b>  <font size="-4"> 

               <div style="float: left;" width=200 padding="0,0,6,6">
                 <span width="200"> <b>CUSTOMER DETAILS:</b> </span> 
               </div>

               <div  style="float: Right;" width="200" padding="0,0,6,6">
                <span width="200"><b>PRODUCT DETAILS</b></span>
                </div>
    </font>]]>

    </parameter>
   </system>
```

Comment: You have omitted the most important information, which is to explain how the "XML" above is being rendered to HTML.  What is the document in which the above is contained and how is it processed before sending to the browser.

Comment: Hi Jim thanks for formatting . The xml file is passed as a object to a winform application and then rendered.I am new to xml and the formatting. Sorry if my answer is not what you asked.

Comment: That HTML is invalid anyway. You can't have a div inside a font, and I've no idea where that padding attribute comes from. https://validator.w3.org/nu/ would be a useful tool.

Comment: hi Quentin , sorry its not an html , Its a xml file that contains the CDATA section. Sorry I should have mentioned that in my question.